# Is there a universal link on macOS that opens chrome to a specific website?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using macOS shortcuts to open Google Meet in Safari however I would like it to open the URL in Chrome since Meet in Safari doesn't support background visuals.

If I have a link like this meet.google.com/xyz is there a way for the OS to open it in Chrome like maybe something like this googlechrome://meet.google.com/xyz ?

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut option for Chrome so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The (free) [Actions](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Actions) app provides an “Open URLs with App” that you can use to open a URL in any browser from Shortcuts. The (free) [Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) app also provides an action for this.

[image: Shortcuts showing the action]